# Display not showing full desktop

Tags: compiz

I have a low cost PC that has 800 by 480 resolution physical size. I was using Ubuntu Hardy , it worked. Now I uninstalled Ubuntu Hardy and installed Ubuntu Lucid . While installing itself it showed only 80% of screen and I somehow I installed thinking that it will be okay after installation. Ubuntu Lucid is installed , still display not showing the full desktop. The task bar is below the actual screen size. If I run any application , it shows only 80% of application, remaining is buried below the physical size of display. I am not able to adjust the resolution also. The resolution is not changing even after I tried many times with x rander.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know if there is any support for such low resolutions... AFAIK the latest guidelines suggest a minimum resolution of 1024 x 768

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

Today's X rarely requires manual configuration. X now automatically configures itself with reasonable defaults. Both GNOME and KDE provide GUI utilities for customizing settings beyond these defaults if you like.

However, sometimes you need to muck with the configuration manually, beyond what these tools allow.

Quick xorg.conf

Most systems don't ship with an X config file any more, but sometimes you need one. Here's a basic skeleton:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

[Configuring using xorg.conf.d (Ubuntu 10.04 and newer)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config)

Comment: And thank god. I was going to transform myself into an X power editor if the auto configuration did not come. Specially with Nvidia.